# C++ how to find out if function is member or non-member. Other words the "this" pointer is available

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, compile-time

The task is that I need a macro that outputs a "this" pointer.

```
#DEFINE thisOutput \
std::stringstream ss; \
ss << static_cast<const void *>(this); \
std::cout << ss.str(); \
```

But using this macro in non-member function issues compile error

> error: invalid use of 'this' in non-member function

How to modify this macro to define if function is member or non-member function and to do its job or not to do?

Addition: Template specialization can also be a solution.

Comment: *But using this macro in non-member function* -- Why are you putting this macro in non-member functions?  What is supposed to be output in a non-member function?  And why use macros to begin with?  Why not a template function?

Comment: As shown this sounds like an xy problem.  What's the really issue you're trying to solve?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thank you for the comment. This is just a simple example. The template would be a solution, but I do not know how to do it with template.

Comment: @G.M. I need to output the pointer to the object with log4cplus. There can be multiple objects of the same class. To log message macro LOG is used. So this macro should capture "this" if it is avaliable.

Comment: @KiskaJoe Couldn't you just have two macros? One for member functions and one for other cases. Simple solutions should be prefered in general.

Comment: Please explain why you want to use it in non-member functions and what it should do there. Currently it is not clear why simply not using the macro in non-member functions is not the solution

Comment: unless you use macros to generate those member/non-member functions you always know if you are inside a member function or not, so there is no obvious need for a generic solution